# Sharepoint Webpart IIS reset issue

Tags: sharepoint

I am currently working in SharePoint. I have a web part in my site it doesn't work until is resets application pool. I do not know what is the reason. I have to reset IIS every time.

Is there any affect of IIS reset on Web part?

Comment: Can you provide us some errors ? logs ?

Comment: there is no errors I am just loading data from SharePoint list in web part. it loads data when I reset pool. otherwise nothing is loaded.

Comment: What kind of web part is it?

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Answer (score 0):

If the data fetches from a SharePoint List ,the data will not show until App pool recycles when you have made any changes in the list.